# Problem using ";and" in fish when clearing cache in my linux system

Tags: linux, prompt, fish

I'm trying to create a function that clears my cache in my system [according to this page](https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/) so I need to add the following commands in a function:

## 1. Clear PageCache only.

```
 sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

## 2. Clear dentries and inodes.

```
 sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

## 3. Clear PageCache, dentries and inodes.

```
 sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I wanted to make use of "; and" in the function, separating each of those commands so in case that there's an error the next command doesn't get executed. 
According to [fish documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#and), you use `COMMAND1; and COMMAND2` for that. So I did this:

```
function clearcache
sudo sh -c 'sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ;and sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; and sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

end

But when I execute it, I get the following error or warning:

```
sh: 1: and: not found
sh: 1: and: not found
```

I then tried to remove the "and" from the syntax to see if that did something different and check if that was the problem and in fact I got it to work.

```
user@debian64 /etc> sudo sh -c 'sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
user@debian64 /etc>
```

My question is, how can I get advantage of the "and" feature in fish, or what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: If you want to use fish syntax why are you running sh (which is presumably /bin/sh)? Also `and` is just the fish equivalent of `&&` in POSIX shells. So what you've written is like `sync; echo 1 >... && sync; echo 2...`. Which probably isn't what you want. Also, there really isn't any point in using `and` or `&&` in this situation. You're just needlessly complicating the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition for `function clearcache` runs the command under `sh -c`. sh is not fish; it uses `&&` for the functionality that fish calls `; and`.

That being said, what you're doing is redundant. Writing `3` to `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` has the same effect as writing `1` and `2`.

Comment: so then are you saying I should just use && instead and it would work?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `; and`